# tweening multiple objects, calling on complete only once

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, gsap

I am tweening multiple items in array.But I want onComplete be called only once. Is there way to write it more readable?

```
for (var i : int = 0; i < _cardsToRollOut.length; i++)
{   
            var wCard : TacticCard = _cardsToRollOut[i];

            if (doItOnce) TweenMax.to(wCard, 0.5, { delay:1, rotation:firstRotation + 0.4 * i} );
            else
            {
                doItOnce = true;
                TweenMax.to(wCard, 0.5, { delay:1, rotation:firstRotation + 0.4 * i, onComplete:updateCounters } ); 
            }
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You could use a [Timeline](https://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/TimelineLite/) instead:

```
var timeline:TimelineLite = new TimelineLite({onComplete: updateCounters});

for (var i : int = 0; i < _cardsToRollOut.length; i++)
{   
    var wCard : TacticCard = _cardsToRollOut[i];
    timeline.to(wCard, 0.5, { delay:1, rotation:firstRotation + 0.4 * i} , 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a common situation and there's plenty of ways to do it. One of them:

```
for (var i : int = 0; i < _cardsToRollOut.length; i++)
{   
        var wCard : TacticCard = _cardsToRollOut[i];
        var properties:Object = {};
        properties["delay"] = 1;
        properties["rotation"] = firstRotation + 0.4 * i;
        if(i == _cardsToRollOut.length - 1)
        {
            properties["onComplete"] = updateCounters;
        }
        TweenMax.to(wCard, 0.5, properties );             
}
```